# disable editing of registry key by other application

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Can we disable editing for a specific registry key used by our application. I want only my applicaton to make changes into the registry and other cant see or edit them.

Comment: Apply security settings onto the key, which will prevent modification. Note that administrator anyway has an option to take ownership and restore those permissions.

Comment: @RomanR: Security settings apply to *users*, not to *applications*.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: This is not quite limiting. One can create a specific user with write permissions, or even just keep settings read-only modifying permissions every time an update is necessary. "Other applications" will have readonly access to the data.

Comment: You could encrypt the data before writing it to the registry. This would resolve the _see_ part of the question. It could still be edited, but not in a useful way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever There are many legit reasons to want to do this. For example, storing passwords or if you app has sensitive financial data. Sometimes viruses look up registry and app data for common software to steal sensitive info. Viruses that steal FileZilla passwords are a classic example of this. So this is a good question. Issue with encryption is, unless you ask the user for a password, I don't know of a good way to make is secure without hardcoding a key and hoping no one deciphers it. Still, it would make it much harder to crack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The registry acts as any other file on the system. You can set specific access modifiers on each key. So if you set the access keys so that only a certain user can see/edit them that is what will happen. For that to work though, your program will have to run impersonated as that user.

If a user starts another program or regedit as the same user, he will also be able to modify/see that key.

An administrator will always be able to see/modify that key. Even if he's not the owner and the admin rights have been removed, he can still make himself owner again.